# suggestion on using not selector in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a table in which first element of every row is a text and rest are text boxes.

**I want to change the back ground color of all text boxes except the last one in every row**.

So I am trying to use opposite approach.

**Please suggest on where should I use the not operator in below selector.**

```
$('tr').find(':text:last').css('background-color','#C0C0C0');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
$('tr').find(':text:not(:last)').css('background-color','#C0C0C0');
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/252/)

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
$('tr').find(':text:not(:last)').css('background-color','#C0C0C0');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
$('#id').closest('tr:first').css('background-color','#C0C0C0');
```